# "CGLIB runtime enhancement not supported on native image" failing during startup on spring internals

Tags: spring, native, graalvm-native-image

IIUC spring is trying to generate smth (bean proxy?) related to:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Main.class)
public class Config {
```

but I'm trying to build native image, thus 'because of that' spring commits suicide in

```
org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator#generate
```

here:

```
    if (imageCode) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("CGLIB runtime enhancement not supported on native image. " +
                "Make sure to include a pre-generated class on the classpath instead: " + getClassName());
    }
```

While I understand what's being done, I don't know how can I fix this problem via turning off this enhancement or what it is.

Note: I'm not aware of any spring-boot niceties regarding native image, and I'm (probably) not using them. I have native image build pipeline, which should discover all reflection, dynamic proxies etc and work with them, I just threw spring ioc into action, because I 'need it' for better testing.

Comment: To use Spring in a native image you need to use its ahead-of-time processing at build time. It will, among other things, pre-generate CGLib proxies which avoids the need to create them at runtime. Judging by the tags on the issue, you're using Spring Boot, in which case you can use its Maven and Gradle build plugins to trigger the necessary AOT processing.

Comment: I'm not using spring-boot, just spring-core, what to do then? Can you advise? I tried to used boot before with native but it build but did nothing, and it seems that boot does way-too-many-things on startup. I'm trying to build fast cli, and (without native) springboot adds more than second in startup (on top of bootstrapping java). So even if native will make it faster, it will be still slower, than weld/spring-core. I will try to fix flags.

Comment: You can use Spring Boot without auto-configuration at which point it will do very little at startup unless you explicitly request it. If you only want to use Spring Framework you'll have to perform the AOT processing yourself. You can use `org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor` as a basis for that.

Comment: I apologise. Could you share link where there is any of this actually shown? I didnt find anything. Sure it is somewhere, but ... I really dont know where. I can fing graal specifics, just the springboot part is mystery

Comment: There's a [chapter about GraalVM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image) in the Spring Boot reference documentation

Comment: Does the program still persist in the latest version of Spring Boot? Maybe it's one of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31238, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31050 or https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31050